# Open a closed workbook, Find matching excel values within a column, offset 2 columns to the left and copy the value back to the opened excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge task that I don't have the knowledge or any idea on how to start. I have a workbook called **"Ink" (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Ink.xlsm)** that gives me the toner count of a set of printers. The printers displayed on this sheet change everyday.

I wish for my macro to navigate/open the **Printers.xlsm (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\printers.xlsm)** that contains the master list

- find and match the value from column B in Ink.xlsm (row 2 and down)
  on column H in Printers.xlsm (row 2 and down)
- offset 2 columns to the left and
- copy that value to column G in Ink.xlsm matching the same row.

As of right now I have the starting code I found elsewhere

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\myworkbook.xls")

' now you can manipulate the data in the workbook anyway you want, e.g. '

Dim x As Variant
x = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value

Call wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:G100").Copy
Call ThisWorbook.Worksheets("Target").Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

' etc '

Call wbk.Close(False)
```

Comment: You don't have any code to loop, compare, offset or copy specific values.

Comment: Well my only problem per say from the above code would be on where to start the loop, compare, etc. and how to copy it back to the workbook. I'm EXTREMELY new to VBA so apologies on my end...also, I love your edit. thank you. @dbmitch

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you'll find people more helpful here when you come back with code you've found and tried to implement. Most are not going to write all your code for you. Good luck on your endeavors - I'm sure you'll find it rewarding in the end

Comment: I would suggest starting with macros - record the steps you do manually - and then look at the macro.

Comment: Consider index() and match() as a method but remember that links to other workbooks don’t always need vba - I pull lots of info just linking to cells in other workbooks.

Comment: @dbmitch well do. thanks

Comment: @SolarMike I have looked into the Index() and Match() functions but for some reason it throws an error. The syntax is written correctly. My coworkers are also kind of boggled by it so I thought maybe a VBA would be the solution.

Comment: So, posted an example of index and match and index-match combined, should help to find the error.

Comment: @FabricioMartinez - if you have errors please post the message and the actual formula - even if you think syntax is correct. The key to a good question is good information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show an example of Index() and match() as apparently it throws an error for the OP...

[image]

Comment: I apologize for not coming back to this earlier as I was sick. However, maybe while I was out a bell rang and everything made sense.

Comment: Just happy it helps.